# How do I replace every cell in a dataframe column with its value in a dictionary?

Tags: r, dictionary

I have a "dictionary" dataframe with keys and values and I would like to replace a column of my main dataframe with the corresponding values of each cell in the dictionary. How should I go about this?

I tried using the collections package to make a dictionary but I don't know how to pass values from an entire column into the get function of the dictionary.

Main DF:
1, Bad
2, OK
3, Bad
4, Excellent
...

Dict DF:
1 Bad
2 OK
3 Good
4 Great
5 Excellent

I want the main dataframe to have the strings replaced with corresponding numbers in the dict df. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a reproducible example next time. If I understood well enough, you can make a lookup vector (instead of a dataframe), where you have the values that you want. Then, you name these values in this vector, with the dictionary values, or in other words, with the keys or id's that represent each of these values in your main dataframe. Then you just use the subset function (square bracket) to replicate these dictionary values, in the same order as the id's appear in your main dataframe, and you just save this result, in a new column.

```
main_df <- data.frame(
    key = sample(
      c("Bad", "Medium", "Good", "Excelent"),
      size = 40,
      replace = TRUE
    )
  )

dictionary_vec <- as.character(1:4)

names(dictionary_vec) <- c("Bad", "Medium", "Good", "Excelent")


main_df$new_column <- as.double(unname(
    dictionary_vec[as.character(main_df$key)]
  ))
```